# How to create user base on data from form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

forms.py

'''

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Login', min_length=1)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    repeat_password = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    name = forms.CharField(label="First name", min_length=1, validators=[check_first_upper_letter_validator])
    surname = forms.CharField(label="Last name",validators=[check_first_upper_letter_validator])
    email = forms.CharField(validators=[EmailValidator()])
```

'''

views.py
'''

```
class AddUserView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = AddUserForm()
        return render(request, 'exercises/form.html', {'form': form})    def post(self, request):
        form = AddUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=...., email=....., password=....)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponse("OK")
        else:
            return render(request, 'exercises/form.html', {'form': form})
```

'''

How to get data from form for username, email etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After django validates a form (which happens when you call `form.is_valid()`) a dictionary is added to your form called `cleaned_data` which allows you to access your form data.

So, after form.is_valid() in your view you can access the name entered by `form.cleaned_data['name']`, the email by `form.cleaned_data['email']` and so on.